# how to replace multiple places of one line by single search and replace command in vim?

Tags: vim

In vim, I want to change from print to print() for such

```
print XXX
```

to

```
print(XXX)
```

If I run

```
:%s/print /print\(/g
```

This one only finished the first part, how to replace once for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to capture the middle part to be able to keep track of it :

```
:%s/\vprint (\w+)/print(\1)/g
```

With :

- `\v` : use `magic` mode (see `:h magic`). Here it's mainly not to have to escape the parenthesis and the `+` (otherwise you'd write `print \(\w\+\)`).
- `print` (with the trailing space) : simple match, you might want to replace the space by `\s+` to match multiple whitespaces (space/tabs)
- `(\w+)` : match one-or-more word-character (`[0-9A-Za-z_]`, see `:h /character-classes` for more info and classes) and capture it (the parenthesis)
- `/print(\1)` : here the parenthesis have no special meaning, `\1` refers to the first captured group

Comment: Nice! Would you mind explaining what is the `\v` for?

Comment: Thank you so much. I think its better if \v \w can be explained.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain the regex a bit

Comment: Thank you!! So it is what in `sed` would be `-r`, nice :)